# How to block network traffic on ubuntu gateway via arp table

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables

I have a network with 80 PC and a ubuntu 12.04 as GW. For security reason I want to limit the Computers connected on this network using an ARP precompiled table. In other words I want a tool that allows access to internet only if the pair `ARP --> [IP-MAC]` is preconfigured and ignore every other combination. With this technique I want to prevent users for changing their IP addressees that are assigned from DHCP reservation, and than access unlimited networks and `escape from iptable` rules. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain a bit further?  It is difficult to see why them changing their IP address would give them unlimited access to the internet unless something was very wrong with the way iptables is setup.

Comment: They change the IP of different roles, for example set on their PC the IP of Finance Department when they are not at work, and this give them the reduced restriction that i have for finance department

Comment: It's not gonna help you: it is possible to spoof MAC addresses too. A cheater can see MAC and IP addresses of a pc in Finance, put them on his machine, and there is nothing in what you are proposing that will prevent them from doing so.

Comment: I know this too, but I just want to make it harder to steal or create a illusion of: "can't be done"
Anyway what other solution do I have ?

Comment: 1) create separate VLANs 2) use programmable switches such as http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003GOFIC2?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00

Comment: Thanks, but i have a CCNA and if I have cisco equipment i will have done a masterpiece :). The problem is that I want to do it using only ubuntu. I remember done something similar using mikrotik that is linux based and I hoped i could find something similar for ubuntu too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested and it seems working

> iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.1 -m mac ! --mac-source
>   00:01:02:03:04:05 -j DROP

Drop if packets came from that ip with a different MAC as entered in the rule
The only problem is that i have to add manually every ip that i have to "protect". For now i have only 2

`*A illusion of protect since exist MAC spoofing` anyway this discourage the users try

Comment: This rule accomplishes just about nothing.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae it has worked for me to block users from using that ip on other machines and gain access

Answer (score 2):

What you're really looking for is 802.1x Network Access Control. This runs on RADIUS, and requires client authentication prior to network access. There are several linux based solutions including:

For the clients:

- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/8021X-HOWTO/
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Network802.1xAuthentication

For the NAC Server:

- [PacketFence](http://www.packetfence.org/)
- [OpenNAC](http://www.opennac.org/)
- [FreeNAC](http://freenac.net/) (currently this project is in maintenance-only, not active development)

Assuming you do not have managed switches capable of running VLANs, you may want to go with PacketFence in in-line mode, described in the documentation. This uses `ipset` to modify firewall rules to allow traffic, but requires specific topology separations (DNS on a separate segment from hosts). The switches that PacketFence can use are listed [here](http://www.packetfence.org/about/supported_switches_and_aps.html)

---

CORRECTION!: There is another built-in way to manage the arp-table in Linux see `man 5 ethers`. You add entries in the form of `ethernet ip` to `/etc/ethers` then run `arp -f` to update the table based on this. See `man arp` for details, and http://gwallgofi.com/static-arp-linux/ for more detailed howto.

---

To answer your specific question about arp tables, make a file `static-arp.conf` contaning entries such as:

```
10.0.0.6 00:0c:29:c0:91:bf
10.0.0.7 00:0c:29:c0:92:bf
10.0.0.8 00:0c:29:c0:93:bf
10.0.0.9 00:0c:29:c0:94:bf
```

Then run:

```
while read -u 10 arpentry ; do arp -s $arpentry ; done 10<static-arp.conf
```

For some reason `for I in cat static-arp.conf` didn't work, and I had to switch to the read -u to setup a file descriptor, not sure why... but this added the entries as listed. You can then distribute that `static-arp.conf` however you'd like, via nfs, git, rsync, etc.

Vlans probably would be a better idea however. Info in linux-pure vlan use is located [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html).

Comment: Thank for your response, but this time I need a faster and lighter solution.
can you help me with this rule: iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.1 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:01:02:03:04:05 -j DROP.... Does this rule drop all packet that came from 192.168.1.1 and have the different MAC that one imposted in the rule

Comment: Did you see the part about /etc/ethers and arp -f ? Will look at the iptables when I get to a computer.

Comment: Try `iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.1 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:01:02:03:04:05 -j DROP`. The `-p tcp` shouldn't be necessary since we're just matching IPs. Otherwise, looks good. I'd load one, test, then do `iptables-save > testfile`, edit the `testfile` to add the additional rules, then `iptables-restore < testfile`

Comment: ok yes that -p tcp was a speedy error, I have implemented yesterday with no errors I will test it today (no time), find a pc and change the ip address

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something simple like this?

> iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source 00:01:11:11:11:11 -j ACCEPT

That way you can set only allowed mac addresses to access the internet (you can include the ip address too and you'll most likely need a nice script to maintain it). Other solutions were already discussed in the comments.

Edit:
I was unable to solve the negation (didn't work), but you can do this:

> iptables -P FORWARD DROP
>
> iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.1 -m mac --mac-source 00:01:02:03:04:05 -j ACCEPT

"Does this rule drop all packet that came from 192.168.1.1 and have the different MAC that one imposted in the rule"
I guess this is what you asked for.

Note few changes - the missing "!" and "-p tcp" - which would drop only tcp packets.

Note2: Remember that the mentioned IP address with different MAC would by still able to for example ping the router. To prevent that you need to do the same in the INPUT chain.

Comment: No, he isn't. That's a MAC filter, but then I will listen on the LAN, identify MACs and associated IPs, spoof the MAC and give myself its associated IP, and I will be surfing at the speed of light while serfs around me slosh in the mire.

Comment: You're talking about the part you already mentioned in the comments. As emirjonb stated he's aware of this and wants just something harder. This solution wasn't yet offered...

Comment: Right. But it ws not offered because it is the most obvious one, among those that will fail.

Comment: Thanks for writing, but i am aware of this solution but still doesn't fulfill my basic request. All the user need access on this Gateway, i want to prevent network access if the combination [IP-MAC] is changed. So they will get the idea if the IP changes they will not get net access

Comment: can you help me with this rule:
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.1.1 -m mac ! --mac-source 00:01:02:03:04:05 -j DROP.... Does this rule drop all packet that came from 192.168.1.1 and have the different MAC that one imposted in the rule